# Google App Engine: Non-western characters in datastore, how to print to browser

Tags: google-app-engine, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, google-cloud-datastore

This is a follow up question to this: [Google Analytics Character encoding of __utm cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829113/google-analytics-character-encoding-of-utm-cookies)

I have the following string stored in a datastore `db.TextProperty` - `Test%D0%AFTest`.  This was read from a utf-8 encoded cookie value.

I'm trying to simply print this string to the browser as `TestЯTest` (Notice the backwards R) but instead all I can get to display is: `TestÐ¯Test`

I've tried all kinds of unicode, encode('utf-8') decode('utf-8') solutions but nothing seems to work.  I either get a `UnicodeDecode Error` or the above text.

My HTTP headers contain the line: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
and the HTML itself contains the meta tag: http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is being stored as part of a URL, you will have to unparse it using `urllib.unparse`. You have the right idea with the encoding, you just need to do the extra step of "unparsing" the URL.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> s = 'Test%D0%AFTest'
>>> print urlparse.unquote(s).decode('utf8')
TestЯTest
```